# Hdfs difference between one big file vs several small files

Tags: hdfs, hiveql

could someone explain what would be the difference in storing one big (lets say 512MB) file and have 4x 128MB for one table? If blocksize would be 128MB? I know that 512MB will be splitted into 4 blocks. But in general what advantage/disadvantage would be to store data in one file?
Thanks for explanation.

Comment: Check if [this](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/02/the-small-files-problem/) helps.